# onclick="parent.location is not working in firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
<A ID ="CustomerInformation"></A>
<table class="SectionHeader1">
    <TBODY>
        <tr>
            <td>Customer Information</td>
        </tr>
    </TBODY>
</table>
<TABLE class="TheBox" align="center">       
    <TBODY>
        <TR>
            <TD>
            <FIELDSET><LEGEND>Customer Address</LEGEND>
            <DIV align="center">
            <TABLE id="table5" class="BoxedIn">
                <TBODY>
                    <TR>
                        <TH colspan="3" width="50%">Billing Address</TH>
                        <TH colspan="5" width="50%">Shipping Address</TH>
                    </TR>                       
                    </TR>
                </TBODY>
            </TABLE>
            </DIV>
            </FIELDSET>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>    
<INPUT type="button" value="Customer Details"
                    class="buttonSuper" name="customerDetails"
                    onclick="parent.location='#CustomerInformation'">
```

The '#CustomerInformation' denotes the point where this script will jump to means same page.But it working fine in IE but not not working firefox and Chrome ..when click on onclcik button it is closing current page and go to main page.I tired like document.location and  but no luck... Please help

Comment: What kind of statement is that?

Answer (score 0):

How about **window**.location instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
<INPUT type="button" value="Customer Details" class="buttonSuper" name="customerDetails" onclick="location.href='#CustomInformation';">
```

This does what you're trying to do.

**Edit**: using location.href

Comment: I cant use like that bcz due to my UI structure.Bcz there are many tables which connecte each other.

Comment: This isn't really valid - you can't put buttons inside `<a>` elements (or any other interactive content).